# In Bash, can I have autocd open an editor if I enter a filename?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, bash-scripting

I’ve just set `autocd` in my `.bash_profile`:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

Now I can just type

```
$ some-directory
```

and automatically `cd` into it. Now, can I somehow tell Bash that if I enter not just a directory name, but a filename:

```
$ some-directory/file.txt
```

that I want it to open that file in an editor (e.g. Vim)? I don’t know that this would be a built-in option, but I’d hope that I could do it using clever scripting.

Comment: And what should do bash if `file.txt` has execute permission? :)

Comment: I assume that it is possible, if you accept this kind of error before every edit: `bash: some-directory/file.txt: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in .bash_profile file

```
a {  cd YourExactPath/$1  }
```

Using this like that;

```
a YourFileName
```

So it navigates to `YourExactPath/YourFileName` .

Dont forget linux terminal uses `$0` to run command so you can NOT navigate to file just writing your file name (if you add function which has same name as your file name, this maybe works but in my opinion you don't wanna add all of filename into .bash_profile.). I used `a` because it is shortest way to navigate into file. (NOT:I am not an expert so maybe there is a solution to solve your issue but at least I don't know how I will do.)